# Соотнести артикулы с именами файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Нужно из массива с артикулами(900 штук) проверить есть ли такие артикулы в имени файлов (15000 файлов). Но есть беда. например PL14444-12 и PL14444 нужно соотнести к одному ключу и в итоге в ответе будет, что у артикула PL14444-12 => 2 файла. Для артикула PL14444-16 тоже подойдет PL14444. И все бы ничего, но есть артикул 1444 и при его поиске файлов он автоматически добавляет вышеперечисленные так как я делаю методом str.find(substr) и вхождение 1444 есть во всех вышеперечисленных именах файлов. Есть может какой-то метод, который строго настрого запретит искать вхождение, а будет искать полное совпадение.

Comment: попробуйте использовать 'Регулярные выражения в Python'      https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого метода. Но есть такой оператор. Пишется `==`